# FlatXmlDataSet empty table (DBUnit)

Tags: java, integration-testing, dbunit

Is it possible to validate that the database has no rows for a specific table with a flat xml structure?
Something like:

```
<dataset>
   <TABLE/>
</dataset
```

but that isn't working because, I think, it only validates if the 'TABLE' exists..

I'm testing a delete..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, I have the same issue and I found the workaround.
You can set all fields non-Required and your .xml file will be looking like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "dbschema.dtd">
<dataset>
    <NameOfYourTable/>
</dataset>
```

I hope it will help other people.

Comment: sorry - could you please explain how to set all fields to non-Required? :)